# How to fix histogram to be printed out horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: java, histogram

I tried to print a histogram from an array, but when I run it, it became one vertical line instead of horizontal line seperated by articles. Where do I need to fix or add more code to solve this problem?

For example, there is an array

```
int[]degree= {15,16,17,18,19}
```

and the there is another array

```
String[]day={'mon','tue','wed','thur','fri'}
```

It should print out histogram that shows degree of the day

```
mon |***************
tue |****************
```

like this. (5 different horizontal line)

but instead, when I operate my code, it prints like 
mon |
*
*
*
*
.
.
.
tue |
.
.
.

in one vertical line (I typed vertically but it doesn't show like vertical line on result screen here)

here is some part of my code

```
public static void printHistogram(int[]array) 
   {
 String[] day = {"mon","tue","wed","thur","fri"};
System.out.println("Histogram of temperatures");
System.out.println("-------------------------");
for(int i=0;i < day.length;i++)
    {System.out.print(day[i]+"\t"+"|");
```

this is where the problem is

```
if(day[i]=="mon")
{for(int j=0;j< array[j]; j++)
 System.out.print("*");}
    }
```

if i continue to friday, it print one vertical line of histogram, with from data of monday to friday all together.

Where should i fix to get the result I want?

I expected it to print out some sort of histogram like

```
mon |***************
tue |****************
```

but it printed one vertical line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a print a day histogram a new line is needed, see the code:

```
public static void printHistogram(int[]array) {
   //int[]array = {15,16,17,18,19};

    String[] day = {"mon","tue","wed","thur","fri"};
    System.out.println("Histogram of temperatures");
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    for(int i=0;i < day.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(day[i]+"\t"+"|");
        for(int j=0;j< array[i]; j++)
                System.out.print("*");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```